# WP All Import only running function on the first upload

Tags: php, wordpress, wpallimport

I've created a function that downloads and unzips a folder, takes all the images in that folder, uploads them to the WP media library and returns a list of URLs so that they can be imported into the post (for each product that is being imported).

The function works great and does exactly as I want, the problem is it only runs on the first import (or it may even be the last imported item, it's at the top of the list but in my head it only makes sense for it to only work on the first and not the last imported item). All other items have empty galleries, apart from the one that works.

Do I need to add 'add_filter or add_action' or something so WP All Import can use it for ALL posts that are being imported?

The function is below:

```
function extract_images_from_zip_and_upload($zip_file_url) {
    // Download the zip file
    $zip_file_contents = file_get_contents($zip_file_url);
    // Create a temporary file to store the contents
    $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'zip');
    // Write the contents to the temporary file
    file_put_contents($temp_file, $zip_file_contents);

    // Extract the zip file
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($temp_file);
    $zip->extractTo(get_temp_dir());
    $zip->close();

    // Get all the image files from the extracted folder
    $images = glob(get_temp_dir() . '/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

    // Array to store URLs of the uploaded images
    $image_urls = array();

    // Loop through the image files and add them to the media library
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $file_array = array(
            'name' => basename($image),
            'tmp_name' => $image
        );

        $attachment_id = media_handle_sideload($file_array, 0);
        if (is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
            continue;
        }

        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);
        $image_urls[] = $image_url;
    }

    // Clean up
    array_map('unlink', glob(get_temp_dir() . '/*'));
    unlink($temp_file);
    //Return the URLs of the uploaded images separated by commas
    return implode(",", $image_urls);
}
```